# Automatically load newly inserted rows (SQL Server database) in ASP.NET webforms front-end?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

I have a SQL Server database with one table and I am doing operations using Entity Framework 6 in C#.

I have a jQuery in my frontend which calls a method in the C# backend and loads the data from the database using Entity Framework.

Now I want to invoke this method automatically as soon my table in database gets any new rows / data.

I don't want to use SignalR, wants to keep it simple as possible.

I am still figuring out the best possible and easiest way to do this. If I add a trigger on my table in SQL Server, then how it will invoke my jQuery method or C# method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I add a trigger on my table in SQL Server, then how it will invoke my jQuery method or C# method?

It can't, at least not directly, without implementing something poorly like a CLR procedure that then invokes your application.

You can look into [Query Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server) to potentially accomplish your goals in a more vanilla way, but be warned, you'll probably be the only person in existence actively using this feature:

> Built upon the Service Broker infrastructure, query notifications allow applications to be notified when data has changed. This feature is particularly useful for applications that provide a cache of information from a database, such as a Web application, and need to be notified when the source data is changed.

Comment: I am thinking to implement a timer on jQuery UI level, which will invoke my backend method after every 15 seconds.